# Hangman Game - Duplicate characters issue in lists

Tags: python

I've been making a hangman game and ran into a problem with the lists. If the user input matches any of the characters in the list, the letter's place in said list is found and then added to that position in a blank list. However, words such as "television" that contain duplicate characters don't work. Instead, it will print "tel_vis_on". Sorry if this is a vague post, I don't know the terminology.

```
def guess():
    letter = input ("Please enter a letter:")
    if letter in word:
        print ("Correct!")
        letterPlace = word.index(letter)
        answer[letterPlace] = letter
        print (*answer)
    else:
        print ("Wrong!")

    if answer == word :
        print ("You guessed it! Well Done!")
        #end here
    else:
        guess()

from random import choice
objects = ["computer","television"]
word = choice(objects)
word = (list(word))
wordcount = len(word)
answer = ["_"]*wordcount
print (*answer)
guess()
```

Comment: `letterPlace = word.index(letter)` returns the index of the _first_ occurrence of the letter in the word. You cannot use it if you have duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that part:

```
if letter in word:
    print ("Correct!")
    letterPlace = word.index(letter)
    answer[letterPlace] = letter
```

`word.index(letter)` will return the index of the *first* occurrence of the letter.

So you'll replace only the first underscore by the letter. Do that instead:

```
if letter in word:
    print ("Correct!")
    for letterPlace in (idx for idx,l in enumerate(word) if l==letter):
        answer[letterPlace] = letter
```

the code loops and if it finds the letter, the generator expression yields the index, to replace the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this if you want. pretty easy to understand if you don't want anything too complicated:

```
def findOccurences(s, ch):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch]

def guess():
    letter = input ("Please enter a letter:")
    if letter in word:
        print ("Correct!")
        letterPlace = findOccurences(word,letter)
        for i in letterPlace:
            answer[i] = letter
        print (*answer)
    else:
        print ("Wrong!")

    if answer == word :
        print ("You guessed it! Well Done!")
        #end here
    else:
        guess()

from random import choice
objects = ["computer","television"]
word = choice(objects)
word = (list(word))
wordcount = len(word)
answer = ["_"]*wordcount
print (*answer)
guess()
```

Nice game by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are replacing only the first occurrence of the letter. In order to replace all occurances, use the `re` function like this:

```
def guess():
    letter = input ("Please enter a letter:")
    if letter in word:
        print ("Correct!")
        letterPlace = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(letter, word)]
        for index in letterPlace:
            answer[index] = letter
```